# Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, dokuwiki

I am using a freePHPchat plugin from dokuwiki. The chat application loads fine when i am using MYIP http://ServerIP/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=chat2 but when i use it with my DNS such as http://MyDomainName/doku.php?id=chat2 the chrome browser throws "Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON" and the chat doesn't load.

I have added the following to my apache.conf. As suggested by other articles. Still no luck. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
        #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Content-Type, x-json, Accept"
        #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
        #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, x-prototype-version, x-requested-with, JSON, X-JSON"
</Directory>
```

Below are my access.log

```
SourceIP - - [07/Sep/2016:20:00:18 +0000] "POST /dokuwiki/lib/plugins/freechat/backend.php HTTP/1.1" 200 490 "ServerIP/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=chat2" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.68.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
SourceIP - - [07/Sep/2016:20:00:18 +0000] "OPTIONS /dokuwiki/lib/plugins/freechat/backend.php?pfc_ajax=1&f=loadChat HTTP/1.1" 200 699 "MyDomainName/doku.php?id=chat2" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.68.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
SourceIP - - [07/Sep/2016:20:00:18 +0000] "GET /dokuwiki/lib/plugins/freechat/backend.php?pfc_ajax=1&f=loadChat HTTP/1.1" 200 698 "MyDomain/doku.php?id=chat2" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.68.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programming question. This is more server configuration.

Comment: Did you restarted Apache after editing your `apache.conf` file? Why not rather place a `.htaccess` at the root of your application with your *Header* settings? Can you share your AJAX call details so as we could look closely to further troubleshoot *(in case of no resolution using Apache)*?

Answer (score 1):

Add **X-JSON** to  **Access-Control-Expose-Headers**.

`Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length, X-JSON"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Content-Type, X-Forwarded-For, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST"`